# Debye-Huckel theory with non-polar solvents

Tags: ions, solutions

I want to calculate the activity coefficients of mixed solvent salt solutions. I am seeing very strange behavior when I try calculating the activity coefficient of salts in non-polar solvents using Debye-Huckel theory though and its messing up my down-stream calculations.

In a simple example, let's compare the activity of NaCl in hexane and water:

Inputs: (hexane / water)

- Density: 654 / 1000 kg/m^3
- Dielectric constant: 1.89 / 80.4
- Temperature: 293 K
- Molarity = 0.1 mol/L

Calculations:

- $A = consts \frac {\sqrt {\rho}}  {(\epsilon * T)^{1.5}} = $ 230 / 1
- $I = \frac12 \sum_{ions} cz^2 =$ 0.1 / 0.1
- $ln(\gamma) = -Az^2\sqrt I = $ -73 / -0.32
- $\gamma = 10^{-32}$ / 0.72

In equilibrium the salt activity should be the same in each phase, $\gamma_{aq}x_{aq} = \gamma_{org} x_{org}$, which would imply that the salt should all be flying over to the organic phase. That clearly makes no sense.

Why does this give such totally wrong behavior in a limiting case?

Comment: I've never applied Debye-Huckel theory outside of aqueous solutions, but does the ionic strength equation really apply directly to hexane in the same way as water? I would imagine the actual concentration to be taken into account would be the equilibrium concentration of the *dissolved* ions in the hexane phase; in reality, practically all the salt would precipitate out of the hexane, so $\rm{ln(\gamma )}$ would be very close to zero.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto I agree. In theory, the solubility is derivable from activity so I was really hoping for a robust way to (roughly) predict solubility without any pre-sorting. It would be nice if the limiting case worked but you may be right that the ionic strength equation just doesn't make sense.